# IF ELSE Statement Not Calculating Correctly OBJ C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, if-statement

I'm making a Pay Check calculator.  However, for some reason the calculation doesn't get exported accurately to the label.  I narrowed down the miscalculation to my IF ELSE statements.  I'm calculating for netPay, and when I place this NSLog within the number brackets used the print out is perfect to Xcode.

```
NSLog(@"Netpay is %f", netPay);
```

However, further down the code my NSLog shows my accurate number increasing in value, causing an inaccurate figure to be displayed in the label.

I have a TON of If Else Statements because of tax parameters.  Please tell me if my IF ELSE statement needs something that I missed or if I am doing something wrong or not approved. For testing I am calculating a gross income of $2218 with 1 day worked.  The online ADP Calculator says it should compute the netpay to be $1,860.87, however I am getting $1896.67 on my testing device.  The NSlog print out on Xcode says that within the equation I am also getting $1,860.87 however the NSLog further down the If Else statements says $1896.67.

```
float bonusRate = [self fetchActualValue:self.bonusTextField.text];
float deductionsRate = [self fetchActualValue:self.deductionTextField.text];
float dailyRate = [self fetchActualValue:self.dailyRateTextField.text];
float daysWorked = [self fetchActualValue:self.daysWorkedTextField.text];
float grossPay = dailyRate * daysWorked + bonusRate;
double bonusTax = .75;
float bonusLeft = bonusRate * bonusTax;
double ssRate = .0620;
double medRate = .0145;
double taxRate = .79;
double M10 = .10;
double E704 = 704.0;
double E2217 = 2217.0;
double MEMW0 = .69;
double MEMW0D = 494.0;
float medgrossrate = (grossPay - bonusRate) * medRate;
float ssgrossrate = (grossPay - bonusRate) * ssRate;
float twoTaxes= medgrossrate + ssgrossrate;
float netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate + bonusLeft) - twoTaxes;
float excessTax = grossPay - E704;
float MW0Tax = excessTax * M10;
double E151 = 151.30;
double M15 = .15;
float excessTax01 = grossPay - E2217;
float MW0Tax1 = excessTax01 * M15;
float MW0FinalTax = MW0Tax1 + E151;

- (IBAction)calculateButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
```

{

```
    if([self.stateTextField.text  isEqual: @"ME"])
{
    if ([self.filingStatusLabel.text isEqual:@"Married"] & [self.allowancesLabel.text isEqual:@"0"])
    {

        if (grossPay >= E704 || grossPay < E2217)
    {
        if (grossPay >= 1610 || grossPay <= 1669)
        {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0Tax - twoTaxes - .25;}
        else if (grossPay >= 1670 || grossPay <= 1729)
        {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0Tax - twoTaxes - 4.25;}
        else if (grossPay >= 1730 || grossPay <= 1789)
        {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0Tax - twoTaxes - 8.0;}
        else if (grossPay >= 1790 || grossPay <= 1849)
        {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0Tax - twoTaxes - 12.0;}
        else if (grossPay >= 1850 || grossPay <= 1909)
        {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0Tax - twoTaxes - 16.0;}
        else if (grossPay >= 1910 || grossPay <= 1969)
        {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0Tax - twoTaxes - 20.0;}
        else if (grossPay >= 1970 || grossPay <= 2029)
        {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0Tax - twoTaxes - 24.0;}
        else if (grossPay >= 2030 || grossPay <= 2089)
        {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0Tax - twoTaxes - 28.0;}
        else if (grossPay >= 2090 || grossPay <= 2149)
        {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0Tax - twoTaxes - 31.0;}
        else if (grossPay >= 2150 || grossPay <= 2217)
        {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0Tax - twoTaxes - 37.0;}
    }
        else if (grossPay >= 2217 || grossPay <= 6854)

        {   if (grossPay >= 2218 || grossPay <= 2229)
            {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 37.0;
            NSLog(@"Netpay is %f", netPay);}
            else if (grossPay >= 2230 || grossPay <= 2309)
            {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 42.0;}
            else if (grossPay >= 2310 || grossPay <= 2389)
            {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 47.0;}
            else if (grossPay >= 2390 || grossPay <= 2469)
            {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 52.0;}
            else if (grossPay >= 2470 || grossPay <= 2549)
            {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 57.0;}
            else if (grossPay >= 2550 || grossPay <= 2629)
            {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 63.0;}
            else if (grossPay >= 2630 || grossPay <= 2709)
            {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 68.0;}
            else if (grossPay >= 2710 || grossPay <= 2789)
            {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 73.0;}
            else if (grossPay >= 2790 || grossPay <= 2869)
            {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 78.0;}
            else if (grossPay >= 2870 || grossPay <= 2949)
            {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 83.0;}
            else if (grossPay >= 2950 || grossPay <= 3029)
            {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 89.0;}
            else if (grossPay >= 3030 || grossPay <= 3109)
            {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 94.0;}
            else if (grossPay >= 3110 || grossPay <= 3189)
            {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 99.0;}
            else if (grossPay >= 3190 || grossPay <= 3269)
            {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 104.0;}
            else if (grossPay >= 3270 || grossPay <= 3369)
            {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 111.0;}
            else if (grossPay >= 3370 || grossPay <= 3469)
            {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 117.0;}
            else if (grossPay >= 3470 || grossPay <= 3569)
            {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 124.0;}
            else if (grossPay >= 3570 || grossPay <= 3669)
            {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 130.0;}
            else if (grossPay >= 3670 || grossPay <= 3769)
            {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 137.0;}
            else if (grossPay >= 3770 || grossPay <= 3869)
            {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 143.0;}
            else if (grossPay >= 3870 || grossPay <= 3969)
            {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 150.0;}
            else if (grossPay >= 3970 || grossPay <= 4069)
            {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 156.0;}
            else if (grossPay >= 4070 || grossPay <= 4169)
            {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 163.0;}
            else if (grossPay >= 4170 || grossPay <= 4269)
            {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 169.0;}
            else if (grossPay >= 4270 || grossPay <= 4369)
            {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 177.0;}
            else if (grossPay >= 4370 || grossPay <= 4489)
            {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 187.0;}
            else if (grossPay >= 4490 || grossPay <= 4609)
            {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 196.0;}
            else if (grossPay >= 4610 || grossPay <= 4729)
            {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 206.0;}
            else if (grossPay >= 4730 || grossPay <= 4849)
            {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 215.0;}
            else if (grossPay >= 4850 || grossPay <= 4969)
            {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 225.0;}
            else if (grossPay >= 4970 || grossPay <= 5089)
            {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 234.0;}
            else if (grossPay >= 5090 || grossPay <= 5209)
            {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 244.0;}
            else if (grossPay >= 5210 || grossPay <= 5329)
            {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 253.0;}
            else if (grossPay >= 5330 || grossPay <= 5449)
            {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 263.0;}
            else if (grossPay >= 5450 || grossPay <= 5569)
            {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 272.0;}
            else if (grossPay >= 5570 || grossPay <= 5689)
            {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 282.0;}
            else if (grossPay >= 5690 || grossPay <= 5809)
            {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 291.0;}
            else if (grossPay >= 5810 || grossPay <= 5929)
            {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 301.0;}
            else if (grossPay >= 5930 || grossPay <= 6049)
            {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 311.0;}
            else if (grossPay >= 6050 || grossPay <= 6169)
            { netPay = (grossPay) - (MW0FinalTax + twoTaxes) - 320;}
            else if (grossPay >= 6170 || grossPay <= 6289)
            {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 330.0;}
            else if (grossPay >= 6290 || grossPay <= 6409)
            {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 339.0;}
            else if (grossPay >= 6410 || grossPay <= 6529)
            {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 349.0;}
            else if (grossPay >= 6530 || grossPay <= 6649)
            {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 358.0;}
            else if (grossPay >= 6650 || grossPay <= 6769)
            {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 368.0;}

            NSLog(@"Netpay 1 is %f", netPay);
    }

    }

    }
```

Comment: I doubt anyone will look, but if you aren't just trying to troll us with horrible code, then you should at least tell us the inputs you're giving and what you expect out the other end!

Comment: Well, first off you should be using `&&` instead of `&`.  It's probably not a problem, but it's poor practice.  Second, you should never, ever make an `if` ladder that long.  Far better to prime some arrays with the numbers, select the appropriate array entries, and compute on them.  Third, what are `E704` and `E2217`??

Comment: *NSLog shows my accurate number increasing in value* makes no sense.  I cannot make heads or tails out of what you're trying to say.

Comment: You have used `||` where you should be using `&&` (or skipping one of the tests entirely, since it's subsumed by the prior if statement test).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
else if (grossPay >= 3030 || grossPay <= 3109)
    {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 94.0;}
else if (grossPay >= 3110 || grossPay <= 3189)
    {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 99.0;}
```

should be

```
else if (grossPay <= 3109)
    {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 94.0;}
else if (grossPay <= 3189)
    {netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) - MW0FinalTax - twoTaxes - 99.0;}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this make a number like $3100 fit both parameters of the Else If Statement if set up this way?

Comment: @DiplomaticMedic - Think about it.

Comment: First off thank you.  I thought about it, and then I changed my coding to reflect your answer.  I replaced the || with && along with deleting the >= that weren't needed and now my calculations are coming out perfectly as you said.  I apologize for not supplying enough information at first.  I've been kind of picking this up as I go, and this site has been a huge asset to teaching me a lot of lessons in Obj C.  I really appreciate you taking the time to push me in the right direction!  Thank you!

Comment: @DiplomaticMedic - You really should use an array/table-driven approach, vs the `if` ladder.  Much easier to code, far fewer bugs, much easier to update.

Comment: I have no experience with an Array.  What exactly would you mean?

Comment: @DiplomaticMedic - If you have no experience programming with arrays, what the heck are you doing programming in Objective-C???

Comment: It's something to keep my mind busy while I am here on my deployment in Afghanistan.  I'm not too sure what an Array is.  I will google it and try to learn about them.  I know I have NSMutable Arrays set up for my pickerViewContainer where I give the User the option to choose whether they are Married, Single, or Head of Household and then another where they can choose how many allowances they claim.  I'm new to this and trying to grasp as much as I can.  If you have an idea for how I can shorten my coding and my If Statements I would really love to learn that. :)

Comment: It's pretty hard to do anything in Objective-C without intimate understanding of NSArray/NSMutableArray and NSDictionary/NSMutableDictionary.